# powershell get-childitems without newline

Tags: bash, powershell, formatting, newline

I like to get all `*.csproj` files within my folders (recursive) and later "tar" them into a tarball. I like to follow [this](https://andrewlock.net/optimising-asp-net-core-apps-in-docker-avoiding-manually-copying-csproj-files/) approach but on PowerShell instead of bash.

What I came already up with is this:

```
gci -r -fi *.csproj | Resolve-Path -Relative | tar -cvf ball.tar --null -T -
```

The main problem now is, that I get the error

> Couldn't find file: No such file or directory

I assume this is, because in contrast to `bash`, PowerShell outputs the files using a `NewLine` at the end of each found entry.

How can I remove the `NewLine` or avoid that it's added in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't with PowerShell, it's the use of `tar`'s `--null` option, which expects the file paths provided via stdin to be null-byte- rather than newline-separated (the latter being what PowerShell uses).

Simply omitting `--null` should do:

```
gci -r -fi *.csproj | Resolve-Path -Relative | tar -cvf ball.tar -T -
```

Alternatively - assuming you don't run into command-line length limitations with a large count of matching files - you can pass the paths directly, relying on PowerShell's ability to automatically pass multiple output objects from an expression as individual arguments when calling external programs:

```
tar -cvf ball.tar (gci -r -fi *.csproj | Resolve-Path -Relative)
```